# Not build App for Nativescript with Android

Tags: android, nativescript

I have a problem with build nativescript for android app. I could build the app, and pne day, the other the build crashed. I ran 'tns run android --bundle' and the log error it's:

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list:
  Error while merging dex archives: 
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: com.google.zxing.ChecksumException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using multiple plugins those depend or inherit zxing library? Can you share you `package.json`?

Comment: "nativescript-zxing": "^1.5.7", This is the only zxing library